# Rails with Redis and Devise not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, devise, redis

I've added [redis-rb](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb) to my rails 5 application in order to take care of backend processes managed by sidekiq.

User auth in my app is managed by Devise.

After getting all my workers etc. to function correctly, it seems that my session store is now broken. The problem is that when I sign out, the user session is not destroyed any longer, thus making it impossible to sign out.

Here is my session_store.rb config:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_myapp_session', domain: ENV['SESSION_STORE_DOMAIN'], tld_length: ENV['TLD_LENGTH'].to_i
else
  Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_myapp_session', domain: :all, tld_length: 2
end
```

I also tried to experiment with the [redis-session-store](https://github.com/roidrage/redis-session-store) gem after encountering this error but this leads to a InvalidAuthenticityToken error.

I don't really want to change my session store to use redis though. Is there any way to solve this or am I missing something?

**UPDATE 1**

sessions_controller.rb (devise)

```
def destroy
    signed_out = (Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name))
    set_flash_message! :notice, :signed_out if signed_out
    yield if block_given?
    respond_to_on_destroy
end
```

Comment: Can you paste the code for your sign out actions?

Comment: I have done so @whodini9. This is just plain devise code. I have not changed anything in this action.

Comment: Can you try adding: session.delete(:user_id) in this action?

Comment: This seems to fix it @whodini9. Thank you very much. Could you please add it as an answer so I can credit you?

Comment: @Herm can we use redis-rb gem for integrating with devise for authentication and session management?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `sessions_controller.rb` add `session.delete(:user_id)` to the `destroy` method

```
def destroy
  #...
  session.delete(:user_id)
end
```